# How to delete record through query in ndb database(python)?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google App Engine. Please bear with me if my questions look stupid to you.
I wanted to delete whole record by query . In this code I am passing access token of record which is one field of my model and delete all records having that access token, but I am getting error "there is no delete() in module". Please give me some solution. Thanks in advance.

```
class deletehandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        access_token=self.request.get('access_token')
        gprofiles=User.query(User.access_token==access_token)
        for g in gprofiles:
            ndb.key.delete(g)
            self.response.out.write("Profile is deleted")
```

Comment: class deletehandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): def get(self): access_token=self.request.get('access_token') gprofiles=User.query(User.access_token==access_token) for g in gprofiles: ndb.key.delete(g) self.response.out.write("Profile is deleted")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delete() method is an instance method. Try this:

```
for g in gprofiles:
  g.key.delete()
  self.response.out.write("Profile is deleted")
```

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#deleting_entities)

UPDATE:

As Patrick mentions, a batched keys only query is more efficient:

```
ndb.delete_multi([key for key in gprofiles.iter(keys_only=true)])
```

Comment: Optimize that with ``ndb.delete_multi([g.key for g in gprofiles])``.

Comment: You should really do a keys only query with: `ndb.delete_multi([g.key for g in gprofiles.iter(keys_only=true)])`

Comment: @PatrickCostello You need to change ``g.key`` to ``g`` - ``keys_only`` will return keys, not ndb.Model instances. :)

Comment: Yes true! This is what happens when you post stuff on a whim! I'll update yet again. Thanks!!!

Comment: Whoops! That's what I get for not running it first. Thanks for catching that.